# What is the axis of the cardioid pattern of a condenser microphone?

Tags: microphone, microphone-positioning

I recently got a [NW-700 microphone](http://amzn.to/1Us6ohE). It's specs says that the reception pattern is a cardioid. However, no axis is specified. Is this pattern along the length of the mic? (Purple) or is there a front (orange) and back (red) of a mic?

[image: Mic Axis]

Should I be speaking from the top of the mic? (Purple) or the front (Orange)? Or both? Is this pattern a 3D solid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cardioid pattern is a 3D pattern and is taken along the front direction of the mic.

This video explains the concept pretty well -

The internal structure of the microphone shows that the condenser surface is pointed in a specific direction.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, the zero degree axis of the polar pattern points straight out from the diaphragm.